# sort and uniq oneliner

Tags: unix, awk, grep

Is there a oneliner for for sort and uniq given a filename in unix?
I googled and found the following but its not sorting,also not sure what is the below command doing..any better ways using awk or anyother unix tool?

```
cut -d, -f1 file | uniq | xargs -I{} grep -m 1 "{}" file
```

On a side note,is there one that can be used in both windows and unix?this is not important but just checking..

```
C:\Users\Chola>sort -t "@" -k2,2 email-list.txt
```

Input text file:-

```
436485
422636
429228
427041
433414
425810
422636
431526
428808
```

Comment: What is it that you're trying to do exactly? "For sort and uniq" is less than precise...

Comment: @rici - i have a text file that has numbers inside it in a column..i want to sort them and remove duplicates

Comment: You want to extract the column (how is it delimited?), or you want to remove completely duplicated lines?

Comment: @rici - i added a sample input above..yes..completely remove duplicates

Comment: OK, I added all the usual ways of doing this. Please try to be really specific with questions; it saves everyone a lot of (guess)work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your file consists only of numbers, one per line:

```
sort -n FILENAME | uniq
```

or

```
sort -u -n FILENAME
```

(You can add `-u` to the `sort` command instead of piping through `uniq` in all of the following.).

If you want to extract just one column of a file, and then sort that column numerically removing duplicates, you could do this:

```
cut -f7 FILENAME | sort -n | uniq
```

`Cut` assumes that there is a single tab between columns. If your file is CSV, you might be able to do this:

```
cut -f7 -d, FILENAME | sort -n | uniq
```

but that won't work if there is a `,` in a text field in the file (where CSV will protect it with `"`'s).

If you want to sort by the column but remove only completely duplicate lines, then you can do this:

```
sort -k7,7n FILENAME | uniq
```

`sort` assumes that columns are separated by whitespace. Again, if you want to separate with `,`, you can use:

```
sort -k7,7n -t, FILENAME | uniq
```

Comment: what does -f7 ,-k7,7n stand for?

Comment: In `cut`, `-fN` selects field `N`. In `sort`, `-kN,M` uses the text from the beginning of field `N` to the end of field `M` as a sort key (so `-k7,7` uses exactly field 7); the `n` suffix, like the `-n` option, means that the sort key should be sorted numerically. `man sort` and `man cut` (and in general `man CMD`) explain all this in more detail.